# How to parse many XML files (with CDATA) in a folder and import to MySQL using Java batch?

Tags: java, mysql, xml-parsing, spring-batch

I have many XML files, the structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Result>
  <ResultDetails>
  <SearchFilmResult ItemType="film">
     <FilmDetails>
        <FilmDetail>
           <Film Code="TITANIC"><![CDATA[TITANIC 1997]]></Film>
           <Imdb>7.7</Imdb>
           <FilmInformation>
                <Director><![CDATA[James Cameron]]></Director> 
                <Actors>
                    <Actor1><![CDATA[Leonardo DiCaprio]]></Actor1>
                    <Actor2><![CDATA[Kate Winslet]]></Actor2>
                    <Actor3><![CDATA[Frances Fisher]]></Actor3>
                </Actors>  
           </FilmInformation>
        </FilmDetail>
     </FilmDetails>
  </SearchFilmResult>
  </ResultDetails>
</Result>
```

I want to make a Java batch program to parse data file by file in folder and import to MySQL

```
create table films(
   film_code VARCHAR(255),
   film_name VARCHAR(255),
   imdb VARCHAR(50),
   directors TEXT,
   actors TEXT
);
```

I have found some useful article ( http://websystique.com/springbatch/spring-batch-read-an-xml-file-and-write-to-mysql-database/ ) but I can't parse file by file from folder, also I can't get value of CDATA. Does anyone can guide me how to do?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are really two questions here:

1. **How to process multiple files within a directory -** To do this, you'll wrap the `StaxEventItemReader` I'm assuming you're using with the `MultiResourceItemReader`.  This reader will iterate over all of the files in a directory and pass them to the child reader (your `StaxEventItemReader` in this case).
2. **How to parse the CDATA elements -** This depends on what parsing technology you're using.  Spring Batch just delegates out to your unmarshaller for the actual XML parsing work.  If you share the configuration for your marshaller and reader, I can update this answer to address that as well.

Comment: Dear Michael Minella, thank you for your reply. This is the first time I'm working with Spring Batch. I have followed the above tutorial. Here is my current source code ( https://www.dropbox.com/s/42yo9fafel4xx0a/films.zip?dl=0 ). Would you please guide me how to complete 2 questions above? Many thanks.

Comment: Dear Michael Minella, thank you for your reply. I have put the source code on Github: [link](https://github.com/samuelwilsone/filmdata)

Comment: I created a pull request against your github repository with what I'd consider a good starting point.  For those in the future looking for this, the pull request can be found here: https://github.com/samuelwilsone/filmdata/pull/1

Comment: Dear Michael Minella, thank you for your help. 
I'll describe more details about what I want to implement.
- I have 5 tables (actors, directors, films, film_actors, film_directors). Each director can have more than 1 film, the program that will insert new director into "directors" table, if director existed, the program will get the id and insert into "film_directors" table.
- When we run the program in the second time, it will get the error because the duplicate data. How can we avoid this?

I have created a pull request about my problem https://github.com/mminella/filmdata/pull/1